# Unassigned Reference Exception, Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public GameObject RIPEnemigo;        

void Rekt()
{
    GameObject RIP = (GameObject)Instantiate(RIPEnemy, transform.position, transform.rotation); //Instantiate of the particles
    Destroy(gameObject); //Destroys enemy
    Destroy(RIP, 2f); //Destroys particles
}
```

I added the particles prefab and everything in the inspector is OK, but it says:

> UnassignedReferenceException: The variable RIPEnemy of Bullet has not been assigned
>
> You probably need to assign the RIPEnemy variable of the Bullet script in the inspector.

`RIPEnemy` is a particle effect

Why? It's easy, when enemy gets hit -> particles -> RIP Enemy -> RIP Particles. I've searched in the forum but I don't understand where's my error

Comment: What exactly is `RIPEnemy`? Have you looked in the inspector and ensured you dragged a GameObject onto it?

Comment: Everything in the inspector is fine, thanks. RIPEnemy is a particle effect

Comment: You probably need an assignment before calling `Instantiate`. Something like `RIPEnemy = new ParticleEffect();` (or whatever that type happens to be). Without a stack trace as well as what actual type `RIPEnemy` is though no one here can answer that for you.

Comment: public GameObject RIPEnemigo;

Comment: You uh...you mean `RIPEnemy`, not `RIPEnemigo`, right? Otherwise that is a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your code I believe that, assuming you assigned **RIPEnemigo** in the inspector or by code, the line

```
GameObject RIP = (GameObject)Instantiate(RIPEnemy, transform.position, transform.rotation);
```

Should be

```
GameObject RIP = (GameObject)Instantiate(RIPEnemigo, transform.position, transform.rotation);
```

That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the script is not attached to any other game object in the hierarchy and it is not duplicated.
The prefab is assigned in one script's instance, but not in the other one

Comment: I am new to Unity. I accidentally added script twice and also to more than one object. It worked for me. Thanks